# How to properly model a Master/Main/Detail kind of relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

The relationship I wanna model goes kinda like this:

1. A master TextResource object that stores high level shared non-localizable data, like maximum length.
2. One single detail object we can call SourceText, that needs to be tracked separately.
3. The rest of detail objects, that we can call TargetText.
4. Both Source and TargetText objects store a string localized in a particular language, along with other localization data.
5. But the string stored in SourceText is the original one and hence, even if the data schema is the same, they're not functionally equal and this piece of data needs to exist and be unique per each TextResource master object.

[image: basic scheme of the described objects]

And the options I've thought of are:

- Regular master-detail tables, but **store the SourceText ID in the master table**... Potentially creating a circular reference?
- Regular master-detail tables, but add a **flag/category column** to the detail table that marks a row as Source or Target... Though this could potentially lead to having more than one "Source" detail per master and could make querying for the Source data less straight-forward
- Store the **Source data in the master table**, even if this means having similar columns on both master and detail tables (and screwing normalization while at it)
- Create **three different tables**: master, main and detail. Master (TextResource) and main (SourceText) would have a 1-to-1 relationship while there could be n detail (TargetText) rows per master, but other than that the Source and Target tables would share most of their schema

I see benefits and potential problems on all four approaches, so maybe you could lend me a hand deciding one?

What I want to achieve would boil down to:

- Have one, and only one, Source string per Resource
- Be able to query Text Resources and their Source strings easily and fast
- Be able to query the localized strings of a given Resource, including the Source one, easily and fast
- Be able to store versioned data of each localized string, including the Source one
- And of course, avoid bad practices and observe normalization

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That appears to be opinion based, which is an option for closing a question...  Perhaps if you add concrete examples of your potential data *(plus any constraints on what data will **never** happen)*, plus use cases on how you would normally access that data?  Then we could comment on your options with your specific context in mind.

Comment: This is very likely to be closed but in my opinion the first option is the cleanest. It is somewhat of a circular reference but not completely. You would have to insert the master data first, then the detail row and finally update the master to have the reference to the detail (assuming you use RI here and make it a foreign key).

Comment: I've updated the question to add some more info, but at this point it's just a matter of design, not that I have a specific problem to solve. But I'd say best practices aren't that subjective and opinion-based, and I was hoping somebody more experienced than I am in data modeling would foresee issues or strengths in any of these options and point me in the right direction.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks, Sean! The early draft I'm working with suggested the 3rd (having all source data in the master table, hence duplicating columns in both master and detail tables), but I don't think that'll fly and my first option was indeed doing as you say.

Comment: Actually this type of thing can spawn religious wars. There is no concrete right or wrong answer for this type of question which renders it off topic as SO. Best practices are only really agreed on approaches to a problem. They are not universal. For example, some people consider using camelCase as best practice. But for others they want to use PascalCase. Neither is an absolute but they are both "best practice".